# How can I tell which process is accessing the filesystem?

Tags: storage, processes

My device has been running really slow lately. I installed "simple system monitor", which tells me that some app is regularly reading from storage at 20mb/sec, and with very little cpu usage on the entire device. i closed all apps so it has to be some daemon process, but i can't tell which one. the process list only shows network and cpu usage, but this problem seems to be storage i/o related. is there another tool for this?

i hope i don't have to uninstall apps to find out which one is causing this

Comment: If you use an external SD, remove that and check. Maybe that's corrupted and slowing system

Comment: I don't have an sd card. Is it possible to run that on the main storage system?

Comment: Sorry. I can't help on that